# set size for default marker icon in react-google-maps

Tags: google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm using react-google-maps library and would like to show the default marker, but with different sizes. I known that I can just use my own custom marker and set its size but that is not what I want.
Is this possible to change the default marker's size?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible; there is no property for size on the [MarkerOptions object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker#MarkerOptions).

You could try find a marker that looks similar to the default Google one and set its size through the [icon interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker#Icon).